# Is there a way to tell case_when something like "otherwise, leave values as they are"?

Tags: r, dplyr

In a survey I have two vectors, one containing respondents' answers to a question (which includes NAs), and one that is a dummy for a specific NA code (i.e. it's 1 for all respondents with a specific NA value, such as "don't know" or "don't wish to say").

It could look something like this.

```
a <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, 7)
b <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Now I want to modify a in such a way that it maintains all the observations, but gets assigned a different value (let's say 99) if b=1.

The end result should look something like this.

```
> a
[1]  0  1  2  3  4 NA 99  7
```

I can get to that outcome with work-around solutions, but it'd be great to know if there's a way to get there in a straightforward manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, 7)
b <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)

dat <- 
  tibble(
    A = a,
    B = b
  ) 

dat2 <- 
  dat %>% 
  mutate(
    A = if_else(B == 1, 99, A)
  )
```

or a very simple direct way `a[b==1] = 99`

Comment: Both were helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

under the assumption that both vectors have the same length you could just create an "index" vector of `logicals` based on `b` and use that to index `a`'s elements for value assignment

```
b.index <- b == 1
a[b.index] = 99 
# or in one line
a[b == 1] = 99 
a
[1]  0  1  2  3  4 NA 99  7
```

Comment: That did help! I encountered a different problem in handling this vector subsequently, but I managed to solve that on my own, so it's all good now. Thank you.